# facing error Non-static method requires a target in SSAS TabularTMSL, Power Shell Refresh Script

Tags: powershell, azure, ssas-tabular, xmla, azure-runbook

I am trying to refresh the SSAS tabular Cube hosted on Azure using Power Shell TMSL Script using Azure Runbooks
For larger partitions i am getting following error, I have tried increasing the timeout for Invoke-ASCmd , even with unlimited time out i am facing this issue.

```
failed: {"database":"DashboardName","table":"table Name,"partition":"table-CurrentMonth"} - Non-static method requires a target.   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AadAuthenticator.BuildAadTokenHolderFromAuthenticationResult(Object result, AadAuthParams authParams, String dataSource, Boolean useAdalCache)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AadAuthenticator.ReAcquireToken(String refreshToken, AadAuthParams authParams, String dataSource, Boolean useAdalCache)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AadTokenHolder.GetValidAccessToken()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.HttpStream.GetRequestStream(Boolean isNewXmlaRequest)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.HttpStream.WaitForAndUpdateHttpResponseContainingXmlaPayload()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.HttpStream.GetResponseStream()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.HttpStream.GetResponseDataType()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.CompressedStream.GetResponseDataType()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.EndRequest(Boolean useBinaryXml)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.SendExecuteAndReadResponse(Boolean skipResults, Boolean throwIfError, Boolean useBinaryXml)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.AnalysisServicesClient.Execute(String command)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Execute(String command)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ExecuteScriptCommand.ExecuteQueryBatch(Server server, String queryStatement)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ExecuteScriptCommand.ExecuteQueryBatches(Server server)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ExecuteScriptCommand.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ExecuteScriptCommand.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

Script used for refresh is

```
$Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'XXXX'
$Objects = @(
    '{"database":"Database Name","table":"tableName","partition":"CurrentMonth"}',  
    '{"database":"Database Name","table":"tableName","partition":"CurrentMonth"}',      
    '{"database":"Database Name","table":"tableName"}',
    '{"database":"Database Name","table":"tableName"}'
)
$QueryPrefix = '{"refresh":{"type":"full","objects":['
$QuerySuffix = ']}}'

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Objects.Count ; $i++) {

    Sleep -s 5


        $Query = $QueryPrefix + $Objects[$i] + $QuerySuffix

        Invoke-ASCmd -Server "ServerName" -Database "DatabaseName" -Credential $Credential -Query $Query -ConnectionTimeout 0 -QueryTimeout 0   
}
```

Comment: We are seeing the same using workflows. Assume it is some sort of bug in the time out too.

Comment: Can you confirm this is timing out after ~1 hour?

Comment: No it is giving this error before one hour only

Comment: @ Murray Foxcroft is this error happening because of time out? i mentioned timeout as 0 that is unlimited timeout

Comment: Added an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Right, this took some doing to resolve. I had the same issue as you. Here are some of the key items that helped me resolve.

On Azure Analysis Services I set:

- ExternalCommand timeout from 3600 to 10800
- ServerTimout from 3600 to 10800
- ExternalConnectionTimeout from 60 to 180
- Turned on Analysis Services diagnostics to get a better view on activity

I also tested in PowerShell directly, i.e. with no Runbook. I got the same error. I then scaled up the Analysis Services to max to check for timeouts. This had no effect either. I scaled it back own quick to avoid financial ruin.

So, Analysis Services was fine, Azure and the runbooks were fine too. I double checked the model. It was peachy too. This led me to look a little beyond Analysis Services.

We are connecting our model to a SQL Data Warehouse with terabytes of data. I noticed that the model refresh was thrashing the data warehouse, so I upped the DWU (performance) on the warehouse, the queries ran quicker and the error went away.

In short, by decreasing the load times from the downstream system the error went away. Check your sources for long running queries and see if you can optimise them (or use a subset of the data) to see if it resolves your issue.